# Crash log fabric cxx_destruct

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, crash

I have the following crash log.

```
# RAM Free: 1.6%
# Disk Free: 90%
0

Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
EXC_BREAKPOINT 0x000000018afdd6b8

#0. Crashed: com.apple.main-thread
0  UIKit                          0x18afdd6b8 -[UIView release] + 176
1  MyApp                           0x1001449b4 -[MyAdView .cxx_destruct] (Adplace.m:50)
2  libobjc.A.dylib                0x198236b1c object_cxxDestructFromClass(objc_object*, objc_class*) + 148
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x198243f38 objc_destructInstance + 92
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x198243f90 object_dispose + 28
5  UIKit                          0x18b32b8b0 -[UIResponder dealloc] + 116
6  UIKit                          0x18afe1de4 -[UIView dealloc] + 1000
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x1988b5954 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x1988ba20c _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 1608
9  CoreFoundation                 0x1865237f8 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 12
10 CoreFoundation                 0x1865218a0 __CFRunLoopRun + 1492
11 CoreFoundation                 0x18644d2d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 396
12 GraphicsServices               0x18fea36fc GSEventRunModal + 168
13 UIKit                          0x18b04af40 UIApplicationMain + 1488
14 MyApp                           0x100069b08 main (main.m:16)
15 libdyld.dylib                  0x1988e2a08 start + 4
```

I can not understand what caused it. The object is free dealloc? Or forcefully try to release it? Can there still be a memory leak (1.6% free memory)?

Comment: Let me guess, you using core data in your project right. ?